# object mocking is not working (its null) and returns NullPointerException on method call

Tags: java, mocking, junit4

Here is my class A under test -

```
class A extends ServerResource {
    @Override
    protected void doInit() throws ResourceException {
    }

    @Get
    public String getUsers() {
        String userJson = null;
        // want to mock 
        UserFacade userFacade = new UserFacade();
        // database call: want to return resources
        List<Resource> resources = userFacade.getDrUsersByExample();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        userJson = gson.toJson(resources);
        return userJson ;
    }

}
```

Here is test class -

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class ATest {
    @Mock
    UserFacade userFacade;

    List<Resource> resources;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
      Resource resource = new Resource();
      resource.setName("user");
      resource.setTask("manual");
      resources.add(resource);
    }

    @Test
    public void testUsers() {
      when(userFacade.getDrUsersByExample()).thenReturn(resources);

      A a = new A();

      // causes NullPointerException for userFacade.getDrUsersByExample()
      String userList = a.getUsers();
    }

}
```

Why I am getting NullPointerException for the mocked object even after using `when(userFacade.getDrUsersByExample()).thenReturn(resources)` ?

Comment: mocked `UserFacade ` needs to be explicitly injected into subject under test. `A` is currently tightly coupled to that dependency.

Comment: You are using a `new UserFacade()` inside your method `A.getUsers()`. So it never uses the mocked one.

Comment: That edit was really poor. We now have to read an almost identical set of code twice. Really...?

Comment: @Michael- wanted to explain only on what I understood from comments and how to do it.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose- ok but that requires modification of my actual class which I want to test. I was thinking that mock should do initialization of object by itself but here we are passing mocked object to constructor for initialization thereby modifying actual class. Can it be done using doInit() instead of constructor? I am using restlet that calls getUsers() directly and may not use constructor at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By getting tips from @Nkosi that we somehow need to pass mock object into the class under test, I got things work for me-

```
class A extends ServerResource {
    UserFacade userFacade;

    @Override
    protected void doInit() throws ResourceException {
      this.userFacade = userFacade;
    }

    @Get
    public String getUsers() {
        String userJson = null;
        // database call: want to return resources
        List<Resource> resources = userFacade.getDrUsersByExample();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        userJson = gson.toJson(resources);
        return userJson ;
    }

    public void setUserFacade(UserFacade userFacade) {
        this.userFacade= userFacade;
    }
}
```

Then the test class -

```
@Test
public void testUsers() {
    //Arrange
    when(userFacade.getDrUsersByExample()).thenReturn(resources);

    A a = new A();
    a.setUserFacade(userFacade);

    //Act
    String userList = a.getUsers();

    //Assert
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Mocked `UserFacade` needs to be explicitly injected into subject under test. `A` is currently tightly coupled to that dependency because of `new UserFacade()` inside the method.

Tight coupling is considered a code smell and poor design. Refactor the class to follow explicit dependency principle.

```
class A extends ServerResource {
    UserFacade userFacade;

    public A(UserFacade userFacade) {
        this.userFacade = userFacade;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInit() throws ResourceException {
    }

    @Get
    public String getUsers() {
        String userJson = null;
        // database call: want to return resources
        List<Resource> resources = userFacade.getDrUsersByExample();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        userJson = gson.toJson(resources);
        return userJson ;
    }
}
```

Test would then need to be updated in order to be exercised to completion.

```
@Test
public void testUsers() {
    //Arrange
    when(userFacade.getDrUsersByExample()).thenReturn(resources);

    A a = new A(userFacade);

    //Act
    String userList = a.getUsers();

    //Assert
    //...
}
```

Comment: ok but that requires modification of my actual class which I want to test. I was thinking that mock should do initialization of object by itself but here we are passing mocked object to constructor for initialization thereby modifying actual class. Can it be done using doInit() instead of constructor? I am using restlet that calls getUsers() directly and may not use constructor at all.

Comment: @MyGod in that case you could create a stub the extends the class under test and override the `doInit` to pass the mock. That approach, while workable has a code smell in my opinion. In the end you still need to inject the dependency into the class under test. Any time you `new` up a dependency within the dependent class, you have no control over the dependency's behavior when testing.

Comment: So that means it will not work using doInit()? If it will work then we have to create a new class then extends the class A and override the `doInit`? I didn't got it correct.

Comment: @MyGod after further review the stub approach would also encounter problems as `doInit` is protected.

Comment: So that means we can't really mock any object of class that extends ServerResource for unit testing ? Using restlet way, I believe it should be common to mock objects directly of resource class and then test any method of resource class. But seems like its hard.

Comment: I got it worked by adding a setter method in class A that sets the mock object. Then called this setter method from test class to pass the mocked object. I can create a stub class that extend the class A and then create setter method inside that stub class and make things work too. I hope that you agree with my solution. Thanks.